# iframe height not increasing automatically when clicking on show hide button in iframe content page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i frame height is not  automatically increase or decrease  when clicking show hide button in i frame content page. how can i solve this issue?

```
<iframe class="" id="ds"  seamless="" src="demo.aspx" style="width:100%; border:none; height:100%;"></iframe>
$("#ds").load(function () {
$(this).height($(this).contents().find("html").height());
});
```

Comment: Seems like a CSS issue, can you also post the HTML parts of your codes?

Comment: hi frnd check the html code

Comment: is the iframe's domain same as your site? if not this will not work as you can't access iframe's content if they are from some other domain

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue:

1. You need to have control of both the servers i.e. the server from which iframe is loaded and the one in which iframe is present.
2. You cannot set iframe height as it is a cross domain issur=e and so it does not allow change in its height (see your console whiile loadind page it will show the error)
3. You need to work around using post messeage: refer https://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/

play around with post message and you will be able to set height of the iframe then

Thanks